# Averaging rasters in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, raster-calculator

I am trying to average 5 rasters in arcGIS using the Raster Calculator and the code: (Raster1 + Raster2 + Raster3 + Raster 4 + Raster 5) / 5

This does not error but I find that the output is identical to the 5th raster and does not reflect an average of the 5 rasters at all.

How can I error check this? The rasters look to be in the same format?

Comment: What version of ArcGIS are you using? You've tagged the question with a release that's been retired for 26 months.

Answer (score 1):

Ah! It turns out that if you have all your raster layers with the same name (month) but in separate folders (year) it just uses the last one in the series. You have to rename all the rasters you wish to average so they have individual names.

Comment: Cell statistics mean will do without renaming.